# Trimming a 3 dimensional array request according to found data

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I have a service which fetches the data for the following

```
Func(List<symbols>,List<fields>,StartDate,EndDate)
```

It will return a 3 Dimensional array of values.

```
Sym1   field1 field2 field3
Sym2   field1 field2 field3
    Date1
     Date2
      Date3
```

That is the x axis is fields, y axis is symbols and z axis is dates.

I also have a cache of some of the above values (which I fetched earlier in) in the format of dictionary

```
<Date<Symbol<field,value>>>
```

The service charges money based on each of the data points it will return. So if we have 3 symbol, 4 fields and 2 dates of data then we will get charged for 24 points.

I need to break the original bigger requests into multiple smaller requests only for the  data not found in cache.

Eg. If I have an original request for 5 symbols A,B,C,D,E and 4 fields F1,F2,F3,F4 for 3 dates D1,D2,D3.

```
A,B,C,D,E     F1,F2,F3,F4     D1,D2
```

Assuming in the cache I have data for the following fields already

```
B,F2,D2
C,F4,D1
```

Then the subsequent requests which I will make to service if optimized and broken will be

```
Request1 A,B,C,D   F1,F3    D1,D2
Request2 A,D       F2,F4    D1,D2
Request3 B         F2,F4    D1
Request4 B         F4       D2
Request5 C         F2,F4    D2
Request6 C         F2       D1
```

Is there some standard way to divide the above into smaller requests/3D array. What is the best way in which I can achieve this? What type of data-structure will suit my needs?

Comment: I may be a bit dense but I have a hard time understanding the logical structure of your data: I do not see any three dimensonial arrays in your examples although you mention them in your text; you appear to have a type `fields` (appears as type parameter to a template) and one type `field` (typo?); you mention "some of the above values" but it is unclear to me what these values are (what types constitute them, and what is their relation). Perhaps you can provide definitions for the types and possible relations between them ("class T1 is a key to a dictionary of T2s etc."). Or even SQL?

Comment: Actually we can assume fields, symbols and date combined to be a 3d array because we have a data point for each combination. The dates can only be continuous while any symbols and fields can be combined. You can see my first diagram type representation.

Comment: I still fail to understand the exact data structure as well as your exact requirement but it seems to be a data matching issue and thus I'll bet you that Linq will be your friend.

Comment: The problem I am facing is with creating new request efficiently only for the data not found in the cache

Comment: Ok. Let me make a simple example with just 2 dimensions, 2 possible values each: A and B in one dimension, F1 and F2 in the other. That gives 4 possible combinations The cache holds (A,F2). Somebody requests "A,B F2". Then you would want to return (A,F2) and (B,F2). (A,F2) is cached so that your request for the missing data would be just "B F2". Right?

Comment: If I understood that correctly then your example request would -- among others  -- want to retrieve "E F1 D1", "E F1 D2", "E F1 D3", and the same for F2, F3 and F4, right? All E requests are missing from your example requests. Is there a reason or am I misunderstanding your requirements? I also do not see combinations of A and D3. Did you just omit a few combinations for brevity?

Comment: @PeterSchneider you are correct I have removed D3 for now. The only point to consider when using dates is that they have to be continuous. So 1March and 3rdMarch can not be combined in one request. The other 2 symbols and fields can be combined as we want.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? Is it: minimize the number of requests subject to the constraints that 1) no data already in the cache is requested and 2) all data not already in the cache is requested exactly once?

Comment: @BenAaronson The goal is exactly what you mentioned but with least processing cost i.e. fewer loops and comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be visualized as follows:

[image: Problem visualization]

You have a dense 3D grid where some cells (the gray ones) are already occupied by the cache. The task is to find the minimal number of cuboids to fill the free space. However, your case is a bit special in that the axes for symbols and fields are not ordered.

I have a feeling that there is no polynomial solution for this problem. So if you really need to find the optimal solution, chances are good that you need to search the entire solution space (using e.g. back tracking). Here is an idea of an approximative greedy algorithm:

```
for each iSymbol
    for each iField
        for each iDate
        {
            if(values[iSymbol, iField, iDate] != null) //already filled
                continue;

            set<int> symbols = {iSymbol}; //the symbols in the current cuboid
            set<int> fields = {iField}; //the fields in the current cuboid
            int maxDate = iDate; //the maximum date index

            bool dateAxisFinished = false;
            bool symbolAxisFinished = false;
            bool fieldAxisFinished = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) //extend along all three axis
            {
                //check which axis allows the greatest extension                
                int extDate;
                if(!dateAxisFinished)
                    extDate = checkExtensionDate(iDate, symbols, fields);
                set<int> extSymbols;
                if(!symbolAxisFinished)
                    extSymbols = checkExtensionSymbol(iDate, maxDate, iSymbol, fields);
                set<int> extFields;
                if(!fieldAxisFinished) 
                    extFields = checkExtensionField(iDate, maxDate, symbols, iField); 
                }

                if(!dateAxisFinished && extDate-iDate+1 >= extSymbols.size && extDate-iDate+1 >= extFields.size)
                {
                    //fix this extension
                    maxDate = extDate;
                    dateAxisFinished = true;
                }
                else if(!symbolAxisFinished && extSymbols.size >= extFields.size)
                {
                    symbols = extSymbols;
                    symbolAxisFinished = true:
                }
                else
                {
                    fields = extFields;
                    fieldAxisFinished = true;
                }
            }
            perform a query for symbols, fields from iDate to maxDate and put result into values
        }

// -----------------------

//returns the maximum date index that can be included in the current cuboid
int checkExtensionDate(int dateFrom, set<int> symbols, set<int> fields)
{
    for iDate from dateFrom + 1 to maxDate
        for each iSymbol in symbols
            for each iField in fields
                if(values[iSymbol, iField, iDate] != null
                    return iDate - 1;
}

//returns the maximum set of symbols that can be included in the current cuboid
set<int> checkExtensionSymbol(int dateFrom, int dateTo, int startSymbol, set<int> fields)
{
    set<int> result = { startSymbol };
    for each iSymbol in allSymbols \ { iSymbol }
    {
        bool symbolOk = true;
        for each iDate from dateFrom to dateTo
        {
            if(!symbolOk)
                break;
            for each iField in fields
            {
                if(!symbolOk)
                     break;
                if(values[iSymbol, iField, iDate] != null
                    symbolOk = false;
            }
        }
        if(symbolOk)
            result.add(iSymbol);
    }
    return result;
}

//similar method for fields
```

This is just a basic idea and might need some improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested approach:

1. Instantiate your result data structure before you call the data fetch API service
2. Populate the result structure using data from the cache for whatever is available.
3. Call the external service/API for the values that are not populated (using the result structure).

Voila you're done. For the #3 step, you can use Linq to figure out the empty slots that need to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

It's quite hard to understand what exactly you want. So, sorry if I have understood something wrong.

## Answer

For the answer I assume that **(this is important)**:

1. Dates are discreet. So, if you query the service for 1 symbol, 1 field for 3 days (i.e. A, F1, 2014 May 01 — May 03) then you will get charged for 3 points.
2. You are not charged for requests. I.e. you will be charged the same for:

   ```
   A, F1, 2013 May 01 — May 03 (3 points)
   ```

   and

   ```
   A, F1, 2013 May 01 (1 point)
   A, F1, 2013 May 02 (1 point)
   A, F1, 2013 May 03 (1 point)
   (same 3 points charged totally)
   ```

Assuming this, the code will be straightforward and will minimize your bills :D

```
// Replace Field, Symbol and SomeType with actual types you use for fields, symbols and values.

SomeType? GetCachedData(Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime> point)
{
    //your caching code here
}

void CacheData(Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime> point, SomeType value)
{
    //your caching code here
}

SomeType GetDataFromService(Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime> point)
{
    //your service requesting code here
}

Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime, SomeType>[] GetData(IEnumerable<Field> fields, IEnumerable<Symbol> symbols, IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
    var result = new List<Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime, SomeType>>();
    foreach (var field in fields)
        foreach (var symbol in symbols)
            foreach (var date in dates)
            {
                var point = new Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime>(field, symbol, date);
                var cachedValue = GetCachedData(point);
                if (cachedValue.HasValue)
                {
                    result.Add(new Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime, SomeType>(field, symbol, date, cachedValue.Value);
                    continue;
                }
                var serviceValue = GetDataFromService(point);
                CacheData(point, serviceValue);
                result.Add(new Tuple<Field, Symbol, DateTime, SomeType>(field, symbol, date, serviceValue);
            }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```